# Shimano 7 speed with click shift not enough range. Can only get 4 of 7 gears

Tags: shimano, shifting

The indexing shifter (lever for down, click for up type) doesn't seem to have enough range to cover the entire 7 gears. Limiting screws are all the way out. If I adjust the cable I can get 4 lower gears or 4 higher gears or anywhere in between, but only 4 gears.

The shifter display will only go down to 4th. It's like there just isn't enough range in the shifter to cover all 7. The dérailleur can move the full range.

The bike was bought almost new with very minimal use and as far as I know the gear set is original.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post a photo of your shifter.

Comment: To isolate if its the shifter or the stretch of the cable : Try this - hang the bike so the rear wheel is clear of the ground.  Pedal slowly with your left hand, and with your right operate the shifter.  It should fail.  Now with your right hand, pull the exposed silvery inner gear cable which is probably beside the downtube while handpedalling.  Does it change gears better?   Mind your fingers in all the chompy bits though!

Comment: Does the shifter click six times?  Or fewer/more than six?

Comment: Clean and lube might get it going.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is for sure in your shifter. Make sure both levers can move freely at any gear (i.e. are not hitting against brake lever mount or other accessories).

Also make sure that your shifter's inner mechanism looks fine, parts move freely. If not - consider lubrication.

Disconnect cable from the derailleur, take shifter off the handlebar, shift to the lowest gear and try shift 7 times up. If you can't so the only option is to replace it to proper 7 gear shifter.

Comment: Ok is seems that working the shifter I discovered that once I get down to 4th if I press on the tip of the lever it engages another set of teeth and can now shift to the lower 3 gears
Does this sound right?
4 outer dog gears and 3 inner?

Comment: @KevAclone to be honest I'm not sure if I'm able to imagine right what you're describing. Please post a photo of your shifter. It sounds unlikely. In regular shifters there are no outer and inner gears, I guess.

Comment: @KevAclone that would be highly unusual.  Please post a photo of your shifter.

Comment: Here is the unit
And the the two pics of the unit with the cover removed
You can clearly see an outer set of teeth and an inner set
The selector pushes on the outer set for the to drop from 7th to 4th. It then catches the inner set to select the lower 3 gears

Comment: https://scontent.fbne1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26198639_10213693931215310_5246667802372532971_o.jpg?oh=fb4e2f85034201faecd11733611683dd&oe=5AC491D1

Comment: https://scontent.fbne1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26197910_10213693931255311_9157725382789199794_o.jpg?oh=1597b01b59f8400d0dab1ecb6f67bc7f&oe=5ABF7AF7

Comment: https://scontent.fbne1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26171703_10213693931935328_3071286314739502518_o.jpg?oh=f1f16cf0dc72c821ca1d3f7dbbb624ff&oe=5AC28613

Comment: @Criggie pics you asked for

Comment: @krzyski. Pics you asked for

Comment: @KevAclone So let's see. Let's say you are at 7th gear. Then you push lever under the handlebar 3 times to have 4th gear and then? As far as I understand there is some kind of resistance and you are unable to push that lever yet another time to put 3th gear? You wrote about pressing on the tip. Which tip of which lever?
When at 7th, you should be able to make 6 same movements of down lever to set 1th gear.

Comment: @krzyski Refer the pics for inner and outer teeth for the selector
 I press the lower lever and it will move down 3 gears. and that is the full range of the outer teeth. The lever is maxed out. 
I then have to release the lever and by sort of lifting it and working it back and forth it eventually engages the inner set of teeth and I can select the next 3 gears. It may need lubricating or adjustment so that it engages those inner teeth properly

Comment: @krzyski I made a mistake. those outer teeth are the ratcheting teeth for the upper lever. The lower lever pushes on the end of those for the first 3 gears and when I release the lever the small dog gear is spring loaded and flips in to engage those inner teeth for the next 3 gears. I gave it a good spray with WD40 and the little dog gear now moves freely and flips in to engage those inner teeth . So the system is selecting all 7 gears now. Thanks for the response anyway

Comment: @KevAclone nice to hear that you managed to solve a problem.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem on an old bike that wasn't used much and lubing the mechanism helped. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, only gears 5-7 worked, wouldn't shift 4 -1.  Took cover off and sprayed wd40 while shifting and it suddenly started working.  No need to replace anything.